# Why does this make a pointer from an integer?

Tags: c

```
 push(equation, pop(equation) + pop(equation));
```

Here is the pop I am using

```
int pop(struct stack *st)
{
   int c;
   if (st->top == -1)
   {
      printf("Stack is empty");
      return NULL;
   }
   c = st->arr[st->top];
   st->top--;
   return c;
}
```

Here is the push

```
void push(struct stack *st, int * c)
{
   if (st->top == 99)
   {
      printf("Stack is full");
      return ;
   }
        printf("TOP = %d\n", st->top);
   st->top++;
        printf("TOP = %d\n", st->top);
   st->arr[st->top] = c;
}
```

It says the second arg for push is making a pointer from an integer without a cast but I do not understand why so if someone could explain it I would appreciate it.

Comment: Why the `putty` tag?

Answer (score 5):

`pop()` returns an `int`.

`push()` takes an  `int *`, a pointer to an integer.

You are passing the sum of two `pop()`s directly to `push()`. The sum of two `int`s is still an `int`, not a pointer to an integer. Thus, you are *"making a pointer from an integer without a cast"*.